Label in new environment with many arguments
The book I translate uses a specific format for examples regarding their appearance and the image below is a minimal sample of it. To get this result I use the environment
\newcounter{example}[chapter]
\def\theexample{\whiteink{\thechapter-\arabic{example}}\blackink}
\newenvironment{example}[3][]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip\noindent
{\noindent\colorbox{violet}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax]{\textbf{\whiteink{\large{EXAMPLE~\theexample\hfill}}}}}}
\tcbset{after=\par\nointerlineskip,before={}}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!20,coltext=black, left*=1mm, right*=1mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm, sharp corners, boxrule=0pt]\textbf{#2}\end{tcolorbox}
\noindent\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!30,coltext=black,left*=1mm,right*=1mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,sharp corners,boxrule=0pt,enhanced, breakable,
                       skin first=enhanced, skin middle=enhanced, skin last=enhanced, sharp corners, boxrule=0pt]#3\end{tcolorbox}}

and a code in the form
\begin{example}{Problem statement}
{Problem solution}
\end{example}

It is possible to add somehow a label command in this environment, in order to refer to the figure from the main text of the book via the \ref command? i found some related posts but it was not possible to reach a solution. Thanks in advance.


you haven't provided a usable example, but the fragment uses \refstepcounter so you should be able to use the standard \label command anywhere inside the  environment


\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a4paper, right=9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showlabels}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% \newcommand{\whiteink}[1]{\textcolor{white}{#1}}% not needed
% \newcommand{\blackink}{\textcolor{black}{#1}% not needed

\newcounter{example}[chapter]

% omit the color definition from the counter setup, leaving it to be managed by the external code.
\def\theexample{\thechapter-\arabic{example}}
% \def\theexample{\whiteink{\thechapter-\arabic{example}}\blackink}% old defintion

\NewDocumentEnvironment{example}{ o m m }{
    \refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip\noindent\label{#1}% <- important, do not remove
    % EXAMPLE CHAPTER-NUMBER
    \colorbox{violet}{% <- important, do not remove
        \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax]{% <- important, do not remove
            \textbf{\large{\textcolor{white}{% <- important, do not remove
                EXAMPLE~\theexample\hfill
            }}}
        }% <- important, do not remove
    }
    \tcbset{after=\par\nointerlineskip,before={}}
    % Problem statement
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        coltext=black, left*=1mm, right*=1mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
        sharp corners, boxrule=0pt,
        % what changes
        colback=green!20
        ]
    \textbf{#2}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    % Problem solution
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        coltext=black, left*=1mm, right*=1mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
        sharp corners, boxrule=0pt,
        % what changes
        colback=yellow!30,
        breakable,
        enhanced, skin first=enhanced, skin middle=enhanced, skin last=enhanced]% sharp corners, boxrule=0pt were repeated here
    #3
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\setcounter{chapter}{28}
\setcounter{example}{1}

\begin{example}[ex:my-lovely-label]{Problem statement}
{Problem solution}
\end{example}

\paragraph{Discussion}
As we have discussed in the example~\ref{ex:my-lovely-label}\dots

\begin{example}[ex:my-wonderful-label]{Problem statement}
{Problem solution}
\end{example}

\paragraph{Discussion}
As we have seen in the example~\ref{ex:my-wonderful-label}\dots

\end{document}


Very detailed and useful answer, thanks a lot !!
